# Excel Reference COM vs .NET

Tags: .net, com, excel-2003

What is the difference between adding a reference to Excel 11.0 from .NET vs COM?

(In C# if that even matters)

-Edit-
To clarify, 
I am talking about the .NET and COM tabs in the Add Reference dialog, thanks for pointing that out Hans Passant.

Comment: The API's are a little different. I don't know if the difference is deeper than API's, though.

Comment: Just curious because I rarely don't understand the question... How do you "Add a reference from COM"? For that matter, what does "Add a reference from .NET" mean? You can add a reference to a .Net project, but not to .NET... And COM isn't a programming environment the way a .NET solution is.. Do you mean add a reference to a VB6 project, or classic asp?

Comment: @David Stratton - in a .Net project, you can add a reference to a managed assembly or to a COM object. These are added through two different tabs in the Add Reference dialog, which is what the OP refers to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean the .NET and COM tabs in the Add Reference dialog.  There is no difference if your machine is setup properly.  Which it is if you see Excel listed in the .NET tab.  That means you've got the Office PIA installed on your machine, either reference will pick that PIA.  That PIA also needs to be installed on the target machine.